# MySQL: Select Results Not As Expected: Newbie Alert

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I used SQL back in the 90s and starting to get back into it for a project at work.

I want to store departmental budget data so I can run queries and use it in Power Bi.

I have a simple table with columns for the department (fund) and corresponding monthly expense info.  I am trying to run a query where I can see the expenses for one fund under the supplies account -- can't get it to work.  I know I will probably kick myself when I see the solution so here we go...

```
Select * FROM expenses

FundID Fund   FY    Account                                  January February March April May  June July August
9999   tester 2019  Grant Assistance to INT'L Individuals          1        2     3     4    5    6    7      8 
9999   tester 2019  Grant Assistance to INT'L Organizations       21       22    23    24   25   26   27     28 
9999   tester 2019  Grant Assistance to U.S. Individuals          31       32    33    34   35   36   37     38 
9999   tester 2019  Grant Assistance to U. S. Organizations       41       42    43    44   45   46   47     48 
9999   tester 2019  Salaries, etc.                              4500     4500  4500  4500 4500 4500 4500   4500
```

Table = expenses

Columns

```
FundID, Fund, FY, Account, January, February… December

SELECT *
FROM expenses;
```

— results in all data from sample table (as expected)

```
SELECT *
FROM expenses
 WHERE Fund = 'associate1';
```

— results in all data for ‘associate1’ (as expected)

```
SELECT *
FROM expenses
WHERE Fund = 'associate1' AND Account = 'Supplies';
```

— results in alert advising ‘empty result set (i.e. zero rows) (not expected)
—- rows/record is populated

Expected:

FundID Fund FY…. December populated with associate1’s data for supplies.

I also attempted query: SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE Account = ‘Supplies’; (Nothing)

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE Account LIKE '%Supplies%';` show something?

Comment: Consider revising your design. A database table is NOT a spreadsheet

Comment: Your last sentence means there is no value ‘Supplies’ in the Account column. Do SELECT distinct Account FROM expenses; and see what you have stored.

Comment: Thanks, 'sticky bit' that did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I realize a database is not a spreadsheet but I want to do more with the database than with a simple spreadsheet.  Thanks though!

Comment: So yeah, you did not have ‘Supplies’ in your Account column, but something like it.